# ext.net RTL doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, right-to-left, ext.net

I am trying to develop a UI using EXT.net .my language in Farsi so i have to program our project right to left .

I found this to set RTL in ext.net

```
The RTL property can be set in several locations, including on the Viewport with RTL="true". We’ve also done the extra work to add as a Global property, and set in any of the following locations:

    at the Page level using <ext:ResourceManager RTL="true" />
    at the Application level using Web.config <extnet rtl="true" />
    in the Session using this.Session["Ext.Net.RTL"] = true;
    in the HttpContext using HttpContext.Current.Application["Ext.Net.RTL"] = true;
```

But it doesn't work .why ?

Here is my code :

```
@using Ext.Net;
@using Ext.Net.MVC;

@model System.Collections.IEnumerable

@{
    Layout = null;
    var X = Html.X();
}
<ext:ResourceManager RTL="true" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ext.NET MVC Sample</title>    
    <script>
        var template = 'color:{0};';

        var change = function (value, meta) {
            meta.style = Ext.String.format(template, (value > 0) ? "green" : "red");
            return value;
        };

        var pctChange = function (value, meta) {
            meta.style = Ext.String.format(template, (value > 0) ? "green" : "red");
            return value + "%";
        };

        var edit = function (editor, e) {
            /*
                "e" is an edit event with the following properties:

                    grid - The grid
                    record - The record that was edited
                    field - The field name that was edited
                    value - The value being set
                    originalValue - The original value for the field, before the edit.
                    row - The grid table row
                    column - The grid Column defining the column that was edited.
                    rowIdx - The row index that was edited
                    colIdx - The column index that was edited
            */

            // Call DirectMethod
            if (!(e.value === e.originalValue || (Ext.isDate(e.value) && Ext.Date.isEqual(e.value, e.originalValue)))) {
                Ext.net.DirectMethod.request({
                    url: '@(Url.Action("Edit"))',
                    params: {
                        id: e.record.data.ID,
                        field: e.field,
                        oldValue: e.originalValue,
                        newValue: e.value,
                        customer: e.record.data
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    </script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://speed.ext.net/www/intro/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
    @(Html.X().ResourceManager())

    <header>
        <a href="http://ext.net/"><img src="http://speed.ext.net/identity/extnet-logo-large.png" class="logo"/></a>
    </header>

    <ext:ResourceManager RTL="true" />
    @(Html.X().GridPanel()
        .Title("لیست کاربران")
        .Width(600)
        .Height(350)
        .Store(Html.X().Store()
            .ID("Store1")
            .Model(Html.X().Model()
                .IDProperty("ID")
                .Fields(
                    new ModelField("ID", ModelFieldType.Int),
                    new ModelField("Name"),
                    new ModelField("Price", ModelFieldType.Float),
                    new ModelField("Change", ModelFieldType.Float),
                    new ModelField("PctChange", ModelFieldType.Float),
                    new ModelField("LastChange", ModelFieldType.Date)
                )
            )
            .DataSource(Model)
        )
        .ColumnModel(
            Html.X().Column().Text("ID").DataIndex("ID").Width(35),
            Html.X().Column()
                .Text("Name")
                .DataIndex("Name")
                .Flex(1)
                .Editor(Html.X().TextField()),
            Html.X().Column()
                .Text("Price")
                .DataIndex("Price")
                .Renderer(RendererFormat.UsMoney)
                .Editor(Html.X().NumberField()),
            Html.X().Column()
                .Text("Change")
                .DataIndex("Change")
                .Renderer("change")
                .Editor(Html.X().NumberField()),
             Html.X().Column()
                .Text("PctChange")
                .DataIndex("PctChange")
                .Renderer("pctChange")
                .Editor(Html.X().NumberField()),
            Html.X().DateColumn()
                .Text("Last Updated")
                .DataIndex("LastChange")
                .Format("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .Editor(Html.X().DateField().Format("yyyy-MM-dd"))
        )
        .SelectionModel(Html.X().CellSelectionModel())
        .Plugins(
            Html.X().CellEditing().Listeners(ls => ls.Edit.Fn = "edit")
        )
    )


    @(X.Button()
        .Text("Show Window")
        .Icon(Icon.Application)
        .Handler("App.Window1.show(this);")
    )

    @(X.Window()
        .ID("Window1")
        .Title("Ext.NET")
        .Width(1000)
        .Height(500)
        .Modal(true)
        .AutoRender(false)
        .Collapsible(true)
        .Maximizable(true)
        .Hidden(true)
        .Loader(X.ComponentLoader()
            .Url("http://www.spadsystem.com")
            .Mode(LoadMode.Frame)
            .LoadMask(lm => lm.ShowMask = true)
        )
    )

</body>
</html>
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable RTL in the web.config

```
<extnet rtl="True"/>
```

And enable RTL for the grid itself

```
Html.X().GridPanel().RTL(true)
    .Title("لیست کاربران")
```